# Linux環境で特定のコマンド実行後にメッセージを表示する方法はありますか？

Tags: linux

LinuxのCLI環境で、特定のコマンド実行後にメッセージを表示したいのですが、何かいい方法はございますでしょうか？

例1)git addした直後に、「xxの修正はyyブランチでお願いします」などの警告を表示

調べている最中なのですが、もし方法をご存知でしたらご教授いただけたら幸いです。

Comment: 特定のコマンドとは不特定多数が対象ですか？それともgitだけでいいのですか？それを実現するためにroot権限は使える前提ですか？

Comment: 前提条件が曖昧で申し訳ございません。コマンドの対象は不特定多数で、root権限は使える前提になります。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

シェル依存になりますが，Zsh や Bash などの今日よく使われているシェルにはフック登録の機能があるので，これらを利用すれば実現できそうです．

具体的には，プロンプトを表示する前に実行されるフックに `precmd` というのがあるので，これを利用します．例えば Zsh の場合は，実行したい処理を `my_hook_func` 関数として定義してあるものとして

```
autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook
add-zsh-hook precmd my_hook_func
```

とすれば結果的に毎回のコマンド実行後に `my_hook_func` が実行されることになります．Bash の場合も [bash-preexec](https://github.com/rcaloras/bash-preexec) というものを使うと似たようなことができるようです．

フック処理において，直前に実行されたコマンドは `$(fc -ln -1)` などとすれば取り出すことができるので，こうした方法を用いて所望の動作を行えば良さそうです．`git add` を検知する簡単な例ですが：

```
my_hook_func() {
  local prev_cmd="$(fc -ln -1)"
  if [[ $(echo $prev_cmd | cut -d" " -f 1) = git ]]; then
    if [[ $(echo $prev_cmd | cut -d" " -f 2) = add ]]; then
      echo "git-add has been executed!"
    fi
  fi
}
```

上記を実用するには，シェル起動時の最初にフックが実行される場合は除外するなど，もう少し細かなケアが必要になるかと思います．

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！フック登録という機能があるのですね。大変勉強になりました。関数の例まで示して頂きましてありがとうございます。実際に登録したところ、希望通りの動きを実現できました。誠にありがとうございました。